# Transferring from Windows to Linux with rsync

Tags: windows, linux, rsync, transfer

noob here,

I'm trying to transfer a file using rsync from windows to linux.
I have this code, but I'm getting an error

```
rsync -avz -e ssh C:\users\file.txt root@123.45.67.89:/var/dir
```

I get this error ***The source and destination cannot be both remote***

And if I try

```
rsync -avz -e ssh /c/users/file.txt root@123.45.67.89:/var/dir
```

I get, ***No such file or directory***

So, I think the problem is with the path of the file on the windows.. I've heard about cygwin but haven't really tried it

What can I do to get the path to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using CygWin to rsync from the Windows box, the local file you want is almost certainly:

```
/cygdrive/c/users/file.txt
```

rather then:

```
/c/users/file.txt
```

Comment: how do you use CygWin to rsync? instructions :)

Comment: install cygwin, make sure it installes rsync and ssh, use rsync!

Answer (score 1):

Writing the right `rsyncd.conf` is a little bit complicated.

I get the error message

> @ERROR: chdir failed rsync error: error starting client-server
>   protocol (code 5) at main.c(1296) [receiver=2.6.8]

and

> 2012/06/10 14:59:43 [9252] rsync: chdir /cygdrive/d failed : No such
>   file or directory (2)

Because I miss the `"use chroot      = false"` directive in my `rsyncd.conf`

Here is an example of `rsyncd.conf`:

```
log file        = c:/rsync.log
auth users      = backup
secrets file    = /cygdrive/c/Program Files/RSync/rsyncd.secrets

[backup]
comment         = Backup this host
path            = /cygdrive/d
use chroot      = false
strict modes    = false
read only       = false
transfer logging = yes
hosts allow     = 192.168.2.252
```

Be sure the `rsync.log` file is created/changed after restart service, if it's not done,  you have some error in your `rsyncd.conf` file and the rsync does'nt use them but no error or info is showed at all!

And so, the format of `rsyncd.secrets` file, is:

```
backup:<password>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the wsl2 env, use the rsync command indirectly.