# Windows to Linux (Rsync and SSH)

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, rsync

I'm new to rsync, so my problem is probably obvious.

I'm trying to backup the folders in Windows Pictures to a remote Linux directory.

This is what I have:

`rsync -av ssh /cygdrive/c/users/Owner/Pictures blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync`

I got this format from: [Transferring from Windows to Linux with rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182286/transferring-from-windows-to-linux-with-rsync)

But I am getting this error:

`rsync: link_stat "/home/Owner/ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/cygdrive/c/users/Owner/Pictures" failed: No such file or directory (2)
sent 20 bytes  received 12 bytes  64.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1165) [sender=3.1.1]`

I have an `ssh` key pair already linked up, so there is no need for a password... Unless I did something wrong and that's why I am having issues.

Thanks!

**Note:**
Had to manually open cygdrive through cd and ls. It works!
`rsync -av -e ssh /cygdrive/c/Users/Owner/Pictures/ blahc@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need a "-e" ahead of ssh:

```
rsync -av -e ssh /cygdrive/c/users/Owner/Pictures blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but still receiving : `rsync: change_dir "/cygdrive/c/users/Owner/Pictures" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 20 bytes  received 12 bytes  64.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1165) [sender=3.1.1]`

Comment: Can you document your complete path to Pictures? "C:\Users ..."

Comment: "C:\Users\Owner\Pictures"       Within Pictures there are various folders, so I would like the subfolders within Pictures to be synced. I think my problem is coming from the /cygdrive/ aspect. I have Cygwin64 installed

Comment: Is Cygwin case sensitive? I'm not too familiar with it. Have you tried "/cygdrive/C/Users/Owner/Pictures"

Comment: Just tried it. Still getting the error. Tried `ls -la /cygdrive/C/Owner/Pictures` and it returned `ls:cannot access /cygdrive/C/Owner/Pictures/: No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you mean "ls -la /cygdrive/C/Users/Owner/Pictures" ?

Comment: See if starting at the top, directory by directory will tell you anything. "ls -la /cygdrive/C" then "ls -la /cygdrive/C/Users" etc.